# Help understand Z order curve range searching

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, databases

After "speaking" with ChatGPT, I decided to test **Z Order Curve**.

The code interleaves 2D data, then search for range x: [2..4], y: [2..4]

Programming code using C/C++ should be as follows:

```
#include <cstdint>

auto interleave_bits_2d(uint8_t x, uint8_t y) {
    using Result = uint16_t;

    constexpr auto size = 8;

    Result result = 0;

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        result |=
            (x & (1 << i)) << (i + 0) |
            (y & (1 << i)) << (i + 1)
        ;
    }

    return result;
}



#include <cstdio>

int main(){
    auto const target1 = interleave_bits_2d(2, 2);
    auto const target2 = interleave_bits_2d(4, 4);

    for(uint8_t y = 0; y < 10; ++y){
        for(uint8_t x = 0; x < 10; ++x){
            auto const z = interleave_bits_2d(x, y);

            if (z >= target1 && z <= target2)
                printf("[%5u]", z);
            else
                printf(" %5u ", z);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

(please ignore the warnings)

## The result is as following:

```
     0      1      4      5 [   16][   17][   20][   21]    64     65 
     2      3      6      7 [   18][   19][   22][   23]    66     67 
     8      9 [   12][   13][   24][   25][   28][   29]    72     73 
    10     11 [   14][   15][   26][   27][   30][   31]    74     75 
[   32][   33][   36][   37][   48]    49     52     53     96     97 
[   34][   35][   38][   39]    50     51     54     55     98     99 
[   40][   41][   44][   45]    56     57     60     61    104    105 
[   42][   43][   46][   47]    58     59     62     63    106    107 
   128    129    132    133    144    145    148    149    192    193 
   130    131    134    135    146    147    150    151    194    195
```

However, this result does not seems very useful, because instead of checking 4 values, we need to check many more.

Simple index on just X or just Y will perform way faster, even it will need to filter the "other" value with standard iterative search of the whole range.

I saw in Wikipedia article about something called `BIGMIN` and `LITMAX`, but I can not understand how it helps and how it can be calculated. About calculation I am asking theoretical algorithm, not programming code.

Comment: In practice, any indexing technique (especially a complex index as z-order-indexing) will only pay off with larger datasets. With 100 entries, a simple index on X or Y or a brute force will always be faster. 
For z-order-index in particular, it pays off when the query range is small. For rectangular range queries, maybe have a look at [this pseudo code for WIndows Queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH-tree#Window_queries) in a z-ordered-index.

Comment: Thanks will check it out. also is hard to find any implementation :)

Comment: There are links to implementations at the bottom of the Wikipedia page ;-)

Comment: these is some pascal code, not very readable. I found some C++ code, in fact I made it to work, but I am still not correct if is done correct way, since I am using only BIGMIN, no LITMAX or Next_Z_something. Additionally I have no idea how exactly BIGMIN function works (full of magic numbers etc). May be is good way to post it in code review website, except most of the people there will judge my coding style and not the algorithm itself.

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59806026/980270) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30170783/980270)? The other question is whether you really need LITMAX/BIGMIN. I admit don't fully understand how they work but they don't seem to be terribly efficient, the search area is not even halved. DISCLAIMER: self advertisement: Why don't you have a look at the [PH-tree](http://phtree.org), it uses Z-order curves but doesn't require LITMAX/BIGMIN. Instead it uses the bits of 12 and 48 (your start and end) to efficiently filter out unnecessary quadrants

Comment: Im sure I did but will "study" these carefully :)

Comment: Sorry, that was inaccurate, the PH-tree splits the dataset into a hierarchy of nodes with 4 quadrants each. Within each node that intersects with the query, it calculates start/end and uses these do efficiently determine which subnodes to traverse. A description of the math behind this can be found [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/phtree/blob/master/Z-Ordered_Hypercube_Navigation.pdf). Beware, this paper is _very_ _dry_ to read!

Comment: I am developing key value database with Redis interface (https://github.com/nmmmnu/HM4) recently I decided to add Z Order Curve there, since not many other databases supports this kind of query. The database keys are ordered (similar to sorted array of pair<key,val>, except they are on the disk and data can be 100's of GB), so at least theoretically Z Order Curve will be nice addition.